# How to grant a regular user shell access to a specific folder

Tags: linux, permissions, debian, cron

I need to grant another developer SSH read/write access to the web root and the crontab on a Debian box. Normally I'm the only person who logs in so I use the root user to do that. This new user is not fully trusted so I can't give him root access.

So far I've managed to create him as a user using:

```
useradd -m --shell=/bin/bash newUser
```

and I've installed his public key so he can log in via SSH.

Now I need to grant him the read/write access to just the web root of one of several sites that run off this server. Also he needs to be able to edit the crontab.

What do I need to do?

UPDATE:

I actually worked out (I think) how to do it.

1. modified the newUser group:

   usermod -g mySiteGroup newUser
2. added read/write permissions recursively to the web root folder

   chmod -R g+rw /var/www/mySite

This appears to work. Please let me know if I missed anything important or left anything not properly secure. Thanks
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you solved the problem, please answer your own question and accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

While not a horribly bad setup, here's what I'd do:

- create a group "dev" / "developers"
- add both yourself and the new user to it (please note that by doing this I strongly discourage the regular use of root account)
- chown the web server root in order to make it owned by the "developers" group
- then chmod it recursively to 775/770 (here's your only choice, as the server admin, fiddle with it as you like)

This should do it well, now for the crontab, here's an excerpt from its man page:

> If the /etc/cron.allow file exists, then you must be listed (one user
>   per line) therein in order to be allowed to use this command.  If the
>   /etc/cron.allow file does not exist  but  the  /etc/cron.deny  file 
>   does
>          exist, then you must not be listed in the /etc/cron.deny file in order to use this command.
>
> If  the  -u option is given, it specifies the name of the user whose
>   crontab is to be used (when listing) or modified (when editing). If
>   this option is not given, crontab examines "your" crontab, i.e., the
>   crontab
>          of the person executing the command.  Note that su(8) can confuse crontab and that if you are running inside of su(8) you should
>   always use the -u option for safety's sake.

Browse the crontab's documentation, and return here to share the results and further questions.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for this answer,  I got pulled away from this task for a while but will respond properly when I get back onto it soon I hope.